# Displaying the content of a variable on webpage in node.js

Tags: node.js, express, var, node-serialport

I have a code as follow:

```
app.get('/list', function(req, res) {
    serialport.list(function (err, ports) {
        ports.forEach(function(port) {
            var temp = port.manufacturer;
            console.log(temp);
            res.send(temp);
        });
    });
});
```

As it can be seen, `port.manufacturer` value is saved onto a variable temp and the resulting  content of the temp is displayed onto console.

When I run the above code, i get something like this on my console:

```
Listening on port 3000...
Tinkerforge GmbH
GET /list 200 219ms - 16
Arduino (www.arduino.cc)
GET /favicon.ico 404 4ms
```

But when I call the api `http://localhost:3000/list`,

Only Tinkerforge GnbH is displayed and not Arduino.

Is there something i am missing over here??

Do I have to save the list in a array or something??

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance. And BTW i am kinda begineer in both node.js and javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that `.send`, unlike `.write`, can be called only once. When called, Express will analyze the data and detect the correct headers (res.writeHead) to send before writing (res.write) to the socket and finally close the connection (res.close).

The solution is to either use `.write` or send all of your data in one go.

**Using .write**

```
app.get('/list', function(req, res) {
    serialport.list(function (err, ports) {
        ports.forEach(function(port) {
            var temp = port.manufacturer;
            res.write(temp);
        });
        res.send();
    });
});
```

**Using .send**

```
app.get('/list', function(req, res) {
    serialport.list(function (err, ports) {
        var manufacturers = [];
        ports.forEach(function (port) {
            manufacturers.push(port.manufacturer);
        });
        res.send(manufacturers.join(" "));
    });
});
```

I'd probably go with something like `JSON.stringify(manufacturers)` instead of using `.join`, since JSON is so easy to work with.

Comment: Hi thanks for replying. I tried your code, but nothing seem to happen. I get nothing when I open the API on my browser.

Comment: @Kishorepandey Not sure what's wrong, but any of the two alternatives above should work. It's hard to help you any further without access to the actual code or a working test case.

Comment: @Kishorepandey Ah, great! Just realized I did a mistake with the `.send` alternative. I assumed that ports was an Array when it infact was an Object. My bad! I've fixed it now ;)